# what is a faster way to do javascript animations

Tags: javascript, performance, animation

i have this code

```
    function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

from the code you will notice that it uses setInterval() to animate a box 
but setInterval() is slow and i want something faster
i have tried:

```
var id = setInterval(frame, -10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
```

and

```
   var id = setInterval(frame, 1/100);
```

but they still give me the same speed, is there a way i could make it faster or is there another method

Comment: `document.getElementById("myAnimation");` is expensive--can you cache that outside of the function and pass it as a parameter? I'd recommend using a profiler. `setInterval` with `0` is the fastest you can get as far as I know, so I'd try to reduce the work each frame requires. You can also speed up your animation using different increments when moving your entities, but this doesn't change the frame rate, just the user's experience of the animation.

Comment: You can't go below the screen's framerate. To speed up your animation, simply do `pos += 10` instead of `pos++` (or any other value that suits you). Also, NEVER ever do `if (.. == ..)` to stop a loop/interval. Always use a more restrictive comparison `if (.. >= ..)` to avoid infinite loops if something goes wrong or if you missed something in your code (for example, if you do `pos+=3`, it will never equal `350`)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame()` would definitely be the way to go

Comment: @blex , thanks , i never actually thought of that